# How can I filter some attributes/text while generating javadocs?

Tags: javadoc

I want to have custom attributes in javadoc like "@owner" "@since-version" which I do not want to be inlcuded in javadocs. is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

[javadoc tool documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#tag):

*"Some developers put custom tags in the source code that they don't always want to output. In these cases, it is important to list all tags that are present in the source code, enabling the ones you want to output and disabling the ones you don't want to output. The presence of X disables the tag, while its absence enables the tag. "*

Answer (score 0):

To offer another solution:

If you are generating javadoc with the Ant [`javadoc` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html), you can add a nested '`tag`' element with an 'enable=false' attribute to make sure this tag is ignored.